# Error in installing virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, dkms

[image]

**KERNEL VERSION 5.8.0.40-generic**

This is the error I am experiencing while installing virtual box. Even erlier while installing other applications on **ubuntu 20.04LTS** it was automatically going to that virtual box environment and was giving an error related to dkms packages, how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the `virtualbox-dkms` package:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms
```

I think that with `synaptic`, finding `virtualbox` and run "reinstall", the packages are installed, but can't test rigth now.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by making sure your system is up to date. Then you need to reboot so that you are running the newest installed kernel.

Once up and running the newest kernel you can begin the VirtualBox installation process.